# Check JSON data element value and return "" if Null for a multidimensional non-symmetrical JSON structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an external data source that sometimes returns a value of null, i do not have access to this data source so i cannot change it. My Angular 2 app crashes on a undefined or null value when trying to display the data. I am trying to create a function that catches null or undefined values and sets them to an empty string.

I have found examples for symmetrical JSON structures, but not non-symmetrical nested loop structures

```
// JSON ARRAY EXAMPLE 
[
 {
  "a":"1",
  "x":null,
  "y":[
       {"k": "3"},
       {"i": "5"}
   ]
 },
 {
  "a":"1",
  "x":"2",
  "y":[
       {"k": "3"},
       {"i": "5"},
       {"z": "4"},
       {"p": null}
   ]
 },
 {
  "a":null,
  "x":"2"
 }
]
```

Current checking function not working

```
//Checking passes in JSON array
checkData(dataSet) {
  dataSet.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.log("checking data");
     if(!obj || obj === null){
       return "";
     }
     else{
       return obj;
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: **I am trying to create a function that catches null or undefined values and sets them to an empty string** Do you mean to change the value in the array? Better will be if you just put a check in your function

Comment: The example you showed doesn't have any null values, it only has some properties that are strings containing the word "null". Regarding your JS function, the return value from a `.forEach()` callback doesn't do anything, plus you need to use the `obj` argument within the function, not `dataSet`. And presumably the function would need to be recursive to handle nested arrays/objects.

Comment: @user2181397 I do mean to change all the values that are either null or  undefined to an empty String

Comment: @nnnnnn updated the example. and function still returning null and crashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a function that will recursively test/replace every property in a JSON hierarchy:

```js
function process(obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
    var child = obj[i];
    if (child === null)
      obj[i] = "";
    else if (typeof(child)=="object")
      process(child);
  }
}

// try it out with your sample data
var data = [
 {
  "a":"1",
  "x":null,
  "y":[
       {"k": "3"},
       {"i": "5"}
   ]
 },
 {
  "a":"1",
  "x":"2",
  "y":[
       {"k": "3"},
       {"i": "5"},
       {"z": "4"},
       {"p": null}
   ]
 },
 {
  "a":null,
  "x":"2"
 }
];
process(data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

```
const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testData, (key, value) =>
  value === null || value === undefined
    ? ''    // return empty string for null or undefined
    : value // return everything else unchanged
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that recursively modifies the object or array passed to it:

```js
// helper function to loop over array elements OR object properties
function iterator(cb, obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj))
    obj.forEach(cb);
  else
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) { cb(obj[k], k, obj); });
}

function replaceNulls(obj) {
  iterator(function(v, k, o) {
    if (v == null)
      o[k] = "";
    else if (typeof v === "object")
      replaceNulls(v);
  }, obj);
}

var input = [
 {
  "a":"1",
  "x":null,
  "y":[
       {"k": "3"},
       {"i": "5"},
       null
   ]
 },
 null,
 {
  "a":"1",
  "x":"2",
  "y":[
       {"k": "3"},
       {"i": "5"},
       {"z": "4"},
       {"p": null}
   ]
 },
 {
  "a":null,
  "x":"2"
 }
];
replaceNulls(input);
console.log(input);
```

Note that testing for `null` using `==` will also match `undefined` values. If you wanted to test for `null` but *not* `undefined` just use `===` instead.